# GeoNetwork not displaying all harvested metadata with Dublin Core schema

Tags: geoserver, metadata, geonetwork, csw

I have a GeoServer 2.6 installed with the CSW plugin.  I can make a call to GetRecords using the standard ISO19115/19139 schema and see all of the metadata.  My main interest here are keywords that I am manually adding to a layer.  When I change the output schema to Dublin Core (outputSchema=http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2), everything looks good... the keyword values all show up as  elements.  All other metadata is properly populated... abstract, references, description, type, creator, etc etc.

Using GeoNetwork 2.10.4, I harvest my GeoServer CSW.  When I call GetRecords using the ISO schema, everything looks just as it does on GeoServer.  All of my metadata is present.  However, when I change the output schema to Dublin Core, almost all of the metadata disappears.  A single Record element only contains an identifier, date, BoundingBox, and URIs to my WFS and WMS.  All of the other metadata has vanished.  If I create a brand new metadata record from within GeoNetwork using the Dublin Core template, it shows every dublin core field, regardless if it's populated or not.  My request looks like this:

```
geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetRecords&typeNames=csw:Record&resultType=results&elementSetName=full&outputSchema=http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2&constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT
```

Does anybody have any idea why the GeoNetwork Dublin Core output schema isn't showing much of the data that does appear in the ISO output schema for my harvested data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any error here.  Dublin core is a minimal set of metadata.  It is essentially the core of metadata that any record needs to have, to be useful.

The below example is a fairly complete Dublin core metadata record:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:GetRecordByIdResponse xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2">
  <csw:SummaryRecord xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
  <dc:identifier>1722a574-9514-3b21-e054-002128a47908</dc:identifier>
  <dc:title>Airborne geophysical data from HiRES1 project</dc:title>
  <dc:type>dataset</dc:type>
  <dc:subject>Geology</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>Geophysics</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>Geophysical surveys</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>Magnetic surveys</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>Aerial surveys</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>NERC_DDC</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject>geoscientificInformation</dc:subject>
  <dc:format>ASCII (.csv) data table</dc:format>
  <dc:format>georeferenced image (GEOTIF)</dc:format>
  <dct:abstract>The HiRES-1 project acquired airborne geophysical data  
  during 1998. Coverage included the Central Midlands of England and into 
  the associated Welsh Borderland. Survey flying for the collaborative 
  BGS and World Geoscience Corporation Ltd (WGC) high resolution 
  geophysical and environmental survey was completed in early September 
  1998. The data comprise multi-channel gamma ray spectrometer,   
  magnetometer and dual frequency VLF-EM. Flight line spacing was 400 m 
  with tie lines at 1200 m and the total area surveyed is some 14 000 n 
  Airborne Resource and Environmental Survey- Phase 1 (HiRES-1):   
  ...</dct:abstract>
  </csw:SummaryRecord>
</csw:GetRecordByIdResponse>
```

The ISO 19115/ISO 19139 record for the same record is 676 lines long.